# Unable to clone gitlab repository?

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to clone my gitlab repository.

Here i provided project-name as repo name and username as my user name.

Command I tried:

```
$git clone <copied gitlab repo of https>
```

When i try to do that i got the below error.

> Cloning into 'project-name'...
>   remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
>   fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/username/project-name.git/' not found

help me someone how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 17):

If someone for some reason finds this now, what helped me in the end was adding my username in front of the gitlab instance url.

```
git clone https://username@gitlab.com/username/project-name.git
```

Apparently it's a bug in gitlab.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by simply adding username to url like below,

before: https://gitlab.com/gitlab_user/myrepo.git

after: https://gitlabusername@gitlab.com/gitlab_user/myrepo.git

Answer (score 0):

You have trailing slash (/) at the end of your url.

Use `git clone https://gitlab.com/username/project-name.git` instead.

Comment: This answer is not useful at all. Infact, its `git` itself that adds the trailing slash at the end of the URL, in the error message. See here ```> git clone https://gitlab.com/xxx.git
Cloning into 'xxx'...
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/xxx.git/' not found```

Answer (score 0):

In windows go to **Credential Manager** and remove :

```
git:https://gitlab.com
```

Now, try to clone the project again