# Custom clone url - Gitlab clone showing an error: The project you were looking for could not be found

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm facing the following error with cloning a project in a self-hosted Gitlab with a custom clone url:

```
 git clone https://username:token@gitlab.domain.com/custom_name/xxx.git
 Cloning into 'xxx'... 
 remote: The project you were looking for could not be found. 
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
 fatal: repository 'https://username:token@gitlab.domain.com/custom_name/xxx.git'
```

I'm using a custom cloning url "**gitlab.domain.com/custom_name/*"** and have setup my SSH key and was able to validate the connection to the server.
Furthermore, I could only get it working by removing the custom clone URL setting put in place.

**Gitlab settings infos:**
Version: 16.1.2-ee
Revision: 0642e8c5c91
Cloning : Only HTTPS
2FA for all users : True

I've already tried the following:

- [remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70983600/remote-the-project-you-were-looking-for-could-not-be-found-or-you-dont-have-pe)
- [Unable to clone gitlab repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843932/unable-to-clone-gitlab-repository)
- [Gitlab clone showing an error: The project you were looking for could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63029244/gitlab-clone-showing-an-error-the-project-you-were-looking-for-could-not-be-fou)

Comment: Why did you set up an SSH key if you're not going to use SSH to clone?

Comment: Good point, I had it setup on while initially testing the access on ssh before turning the ssh cloning off.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by upgrading the gitlab version to v16.6